# Android Studio is showing Unresolved reference: Gson even though I have it in gradle and it works

Tags: android, android-studio, gradle, compiler-errors, gson

After upgrading to gradle version 7, Gson is showing like it's missing, but it's actually is working.

I have it in gradle the same way I had before. Everything works fine, but Android Studio is marking all uses of Gson as Unresolved reference.
It's not a huge problem, but I dont want a lot of my files to be marked as error in A.S.

I have tried to clean, rebuild and invalidate caches.

Any suggestions? :)

[image: Gson gradle dependency]

[image: Gson usage showing error]

[image: Import from Gson library showing error]

Comment: Try File -> Invalidate caches & restart once. And if that doesn't work then Build -> Clean Project & then rebuild.

Comment: if not working -> Invalidate caches -> try `com.google.code.gson:gson:2.8.8` updating package

Comment: As I said, I tried invalidating caches and cleaning, but it did not work.
However @BroscR suggestion about upgrading did actually work. Strange that Android Studio did not suggest the new version.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If it's not working to Invalidate caches -> try `com.google.code.gson:gson:2.8.8` updating package.

Worth to mention:
Android Studio does apperantly not always suggest the newest version in gradle. Check the dependency's repo to see the latest version.

Comment: Had to still Invalidate Caches and restart At the time of this comment gson version is com.google.code.gson:gson:2.10.1